# Django - login()-function seems broken

Tags: python, django, django-users

After being forced to leave PHP behind and work a bit with Python and Django I have hit a little problem.

What I'm trying to do is to use the built-in user-authentication that comes with Django. Problem is that when I'm trying to use the "login()" function it doesn't save the user in the session, or wherever it should be saved.

My code looks like this:

```
@csrf_exempt    
def dologin(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
            return render_to_response('bsys/profile.html', {'message': 'Success!', 'user': request.user.get_full_name()})
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            return render_to_response('bsys/login.html', {'message': 'Disabled!'})
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        return render_to_response('bsys/login.html', {'message': 'Sumthin Wong!'})
```

So problem is when I run:

```
request.user.get_full_name()
```

It says:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError   
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'get_full_name'
```

So apparently it doesn't log in the user.

When I do the same, but using:

```
user.get_full_name()
```

It works, then the authenticate-function apparently works well too. So there is something about login(), I guess.

What I also tried was to login via the admin-login as an admin, then using the same request.user.get_full_name() from another view and it works fine.

Any ideas to solve this? Maybe I just missed some essential part of the framework.

Comment: Where are you calling `request.user.get_full_name()`

Comment: `return render_to_response('bsys/profilemhtm', {'message': 'Success!', 'user': request.user.get_full_name()})` But also from other views. It's in the above code, you just have to scroll sideways :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you check that the user is logged in is causing this.

instead of:

```
if user is not None:
```

try with:

```
if user.is_authenticated:
```

This was it will get round the AnonymousUser case.

(it may be, don't remember from the top of my head)

```
if user.is_authenticated():
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't have any effect. Even if I skip the whole if-sets and goes straight from authenticate to login, the generated error-page says that it's an anonymous user.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you rendering a template on successful login? Like with all POSTed HTTP requests, it's a good idea to redirect on success to reduce the chance of the user resubmitting the request.

More relevantly, I believe this will fix your problem because the templates, when they get their context populated with the `auth` context processor, will have their `{{ user }}` variable set to the value of `request.user`, which is an anonymous user at the beginning of the request. If you redirect, the new request will have a non-anonymous `request.user`, so the template's value should be populated properly.

Comment: Adjusted after your suggestions, still the problem seem to be that `login()` doesn't login the user. It runs and leaves an anonymous user in `request.user`. I redirected it with `return HttpResponseRedirect('/bsys/profile/')`, but soon as profile picks it up. The user is anonymous, if I instead log in with the Django Admin-page and go to my profile-page, it works.

Comment: Sorry, `user is not None` is good enough. I'll delete that comment.